# Button doesn't work in registration form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-registration

Everything works fine but the button in the registration doc is not working, nothing happens when I click It...I have added the code for URLs , views and template below 
URLS

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^register', views.register , name = 'register'),

]
```

VIEWS

```
def register(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('/index')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
else:
    form = UserCreationForm()

    args = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'reg.html',args)
```

REG.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Register</title>
{% load staticfiles %}
</head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=" {% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" type = 'text/css'/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=" {% static 'css/bootstrap-theme.min.css' %}" type = 'text/css'/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=" {% static 'css/fontAwesome.css' %}" type = 'text/css'/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=" {% static 'css/tooplate-style.css' %}" type = 'text/css'/>

<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <h1> Registration form</h1><br>
    <img src="{% static 'img/53471658c4ed95e72a2ed6058361a367.jpg' %}" alt="HI" align="right">


<form method="post">

{{ form.as_ul }}
<br>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>


 </form>


  </div>

    </body> 
  </html>
```

Comment: Your view code is not well-indented. Could that be a problem. In your form make it look like this`<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`. And try to put more effort into making your question clear

Comment: If you get an error that your post is too much code, please don't pad it with useless text. I've removed the spammy bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the type to "submit" and add a value "Submit" to your button. Also, add an action to your form.

```
<form method="post" action="">

    {{ form.as_ul }}
    <br>
    <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
</form>
```